# Create text fields in Flash CS5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Im probably some 4 hours old working with flash CS5, and im trying to create a website that just displays a goggle map with two text fields that the user would enter some details(its for demo purposes), Have no issue with the google Map Part, but i have probably the dumbest Question ever, how do i create a textfield in flash. Or am i using the wrong tool for the task?
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to do so via AS3, it's really simple.  Given some parent clip you'd like the textfield to be placed into

```
var tfTextfieldName:TextField = new TextField();
tfTextfieldName.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
tfTextfieldName.border = true;
tfTextfieldName.x = 10;
tfTextfieldName.y = 10;
tfTextfieldName.multiline = true;
tfTextfieldName.wordWrap = true;
parentClip.addChild(tfTextfieldName);
```

I took this straight from the [Adobe doc page for the Textfield Class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#TextField%28%29).  There you'll all the events/properties available.

Comment: i knew i was being dumb, so easy. Thank You so Much